# Django - Comments

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I'm having problems with comment forms. I just want to add a text field for comment on a specific Post's page, but it is hidden. Here is my `models.py` file in `blog` app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_posted']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.author, self.date_posted)
```

`forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content',)
```

`views.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic import DetailView 
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.views.generic import DeleteView
from .forms import CommentForm
from .models import Post
from .models import Comment


def home(request):
    context = {
        'title': 'Home',
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name='posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 7


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name='posts'
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


def post_detail(request, slug):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                           'form': comment_form})


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False



class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

and finally, the `post_detail.html` template where everything should be displayed:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">
                    {{ object.author }}
                </a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted  | date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                {% if object.author == user %}
                    <div>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <h2 class="article-title">
                {{ object.title }}
            </h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <div>
        <strong><h2>Comments Section</h2></strong>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Leave A Comment</legend>
                {{ form | crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Leave A Comment</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul>
            {% for comment in object.comments.all %}
                <div>
                    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
                    {{ comment.author }} - {{ comment.date_posted  | date:"F d, Y" }}
                    <br>
                    {{ comment.content }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image: There is no text field between 'Leave A Comment' and submit button]

I am stuck with the problem. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You have 2 post detail views... Which one are you using to render the template

Comment: I've noticed it too. Say, I'll use a function-based one, also I edited the code above